# Can "to come/ get to grips with" be used in the following sentence to imply "to understand"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want to **come/get to grips with** a lot of social issues like poverty and malnutrition.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a very formal sentence. I want to gain a thorough understanding of many social issues such as poverty and malnutrition. Good luck with that application.

Answer (score -2):

You can use 'get to grips with' in that context.  I intepret it as to get up close to something so that you can understand it, and/or tackle it.

'Come' doesn't work in the sentence, as far as I can see.

Comment: *Come to grips with*, specifically using *come*, is [a very common idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to+grips+with). Though I notice that *get to grips with* is also used, so this may be a dialectical variation, and you may have been exposed to the *get* but not the *come* version.

Comment: @DanBron Are you an Am E or Br E speaker? I'm British and _come to grips with_  sounds very unusual to me.

Comment: @BoldBen AmE. That's what I was suggesting with *dialectical differences* in my prior comment. The statement *come doesn't work in this sentence* is incorrect, because it does for very many people (AmE speakers), but perhaps it can be repaired by adding the qualifier "in British English". But as it stands, the answer is misleading.

Comment: I have no idea what *get to grips with* might mean; I have never heard such a thing in my life.

Comment: @DanBron Yeah, two nations separated by a single language:-)